# Run a set of thread groups in JMeter consecutively and concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Let’s say I have 6 thread groups A,B,C,D,E,F

I would like to run them in this order

1. A
2. And then B and C concurrently
3. And then D
4. And then E and F concurrently

I have a mix of regular thread groups and Concurrency Thread Groups. Is it possible to do this? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Run Test Group consecutively is uncheked in Test Plan,

If you put A as [setUp Thread_Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

> these type of threads execute before the test proceeds to the executing of regular Thread Groups.

and D as [tearDown Thread_Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group)

> these type of threads execute after the test has finished executing its regular Thread Groups.

You can achieve 1,2,3

4 - I suggest you execute another JMX when finished